# How does one perform conditional statments on SMOB types?

Tags: c, guile

I know that Guile has a `scm_assert_smob_type` function, but I do not believe that it returns a boolean.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
if (type(smob) == int_smob)
{
    int_foo(smob);
}

else if (type(smob) == string_smob)
{
    string_foo(smob);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `scm_assert_smob_type`'s [definition](https://github.com/cky/guile/blob/972fb41f0ce124d97f5cf64bde1075510cd21e18/libguile/smob.c#L57) for hints:

```
void
scm_assert_smob_type (scm_t_bits tag, SCM val)
{
  if (!SCM_SMOB_PREDICATE (tag, val))
    scm_wrong_type_arg_msg (NULL, 0, val, scm_smobs[SCM_TC2SMOBNUM(tag)].name);
}
```

As you can see, it utilizes [`SCM_SMOB_PREDICATE`](https://github.com/cky/guile/blob/972fb41f0ce124d97f5cf64bde1075510cd21e18/libguile/smob.h#L54) which does return a boolean. The macro is for public use and is defined in `<smob.h>`.